# Magento 2 : system config

Tags: magento2, system.xml, system-config, system-configuration

**app/code/Vendor/Paypal/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="web" translate="label" type="text"  showInDefault="1"
                 showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="unsecure" translate="label" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="frontend_url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Frontend Url</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**app/etc/config.php**

```
'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'web' => [
                'unsecure' => [
                    'frontend_url' => '${FRONTEND_URL}us/'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

    'websites' => [
        'us' => [
             'web' => [
                 'unsecure' => [
                     'frontend_url' => '${FRONTEND_URL}us/'
                 ]
             ],
             'carriers' => [
                 'freeshipping' => [
                     'active' => 1
                 ]
             ]
         ],
         'uk' => [
             'web' => [
                 'unsecure' => [
                     'frontend_url' => '${FRONTEND_URL}uk/'
                 ]
             ],
             'carriers' => [
                 'freeshipping' => [
                     'active' => 0
                 ]
             ]
         ],
         'eu' => [
             'web' => [
                 'unsecure' => [
                     'frontend_url' => '${FRONTEND_URL}eu/'
                 ]
             ],
             'carriers' => [
                 'freeshipping' => [
                     'active' => 0
                 ]
             ]
         ]
     ]
```

In admin it only appears in default scope also it has [global] scope in field.

Question - why i am not seeing this field in other website & store views ?
I am always getting this "us" frontend url not store specific.
why ?

Comment: config.php? Did you run bin/magento app:config:dump after your change?

Comment: config.php?
Yes
& this changes are already there in site, i have not made changes.

The issue is i am not getting proper frontend url as per the scope.

Comment: Also the field is not visible any where (any scope) except default scope

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: You can add eighter manually on config.php or use magento command above